# ¿Se puede detectar cuando una función se ejecuta desde la consola del navegador?

Tags: javascript, funciones, dev-tools

Quiero que si alguien ejecuta una funcion en la consola del navegador, lo pueda detectar para evitar que se use la funcion, pero eso se puede hacer?

Comment: Creo que a tu pregunta le falta algo mas de desarrollo consulta [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 2):

Asumiendo a que con *consola* te refieres a las herramientas de desarrollador...

**No se puede detectar si una función se ha llamado desde la consola o no**, lo máximo que se puede hacer es, de una manera heurística, intentar detectar si la consola está abierta: dado que la sentencia `debugger;` sólo tiene efecto con la consola abierta, puedes crear algo como

```js
function detectDevTool() {
  const time = 10;
  const start = performance.now();
  debugger;
  const end = performance.now();
  if (end - start > time) {
    console.log("devTool open")
    return true;
  }
  console.log("devTool NOT open")
  return false;
}
  
setInterval(detectDevTool, 1000);
```

Pero un usuario con conocimientos puede desactivar todos los breakpoints, inhabilitando esta funcionalidad.

Otra forma de detectar su uso sería comprobando si el tamaño de la página difiere del tamaño de la ventana, pero tampoco es 100% seguro:

- algunas extensiones de los navegadores abren paneles laterales que podrían causar falsos positivos
- Si la herramienta se abre en modo "detached" (en su propia ventana) no sería detectada.

#### En resumen:

- No hay un modo 100% seguro de saber si la consola está siendo usada.
- No hay manera de averiguar si una función ha sido llamada desde la consola por el usuario.
- Existen extensiones que podrían hacer estas llamadas sin abrir la consola (greaseMonkey, tamperMonkey)

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, creo que esto me podría sevir

Answer (score 2):

No es compatible con todos los navegadores, pero podrías usar:

- [`Error.captureStackTrace()`](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_error_capturestacktrace_targetobject_constructoropt)

  > Una función V8 **no estándar** que crea la propiedad de stack en una instancia de Error.
- [`Error.prototype.stack`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/Stack)

  > La propiedad de stack **no estándar** de los objetos Error ofrece un rastro de qué funciones se llamaron, en qué orden, desde qué línea y archivo, y con qué argumentos.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
function trace() {
  let obj = {};
  if ('captureStackTrace' in Error) {
    Error.captureStackTrace(obj, trace);
  } else {
    obj.stack = new Error('trace').stack;
  }

  let fromConsole = obj.stack.includes('<anonymous>:1:1') ||
    obj.stack.includes('@debugger');

  // Log
  console.log('From console: ', fromConsole);
  console.log('Stack: ', obj.stack);
}

function doSomething() {
  trace();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="doSomething()">Clic</button>
```