# ¿Se puede acceder a la funcion de orden superior desde el callback?

Tags: javascript, funciones, callback

estoy intentando hacer que una función callback realice cierta acción en función de si la llama una u otra función de orden superior.

¿existe alguna manera de que la función callback acceda a la función que la llamó?
Es decir, si un callback pueda saber que función de orden superior le hizo la llamada a ejecutarse.

una representación de lo que quisiera que haga el código es algo como esto:

```js
function callback(){
  if (/*funcion1*/){ 
    // Codigo1 ...
  } else if (/*funcion2*/){
    // Codigo2 ...
  }
}


function funcion1(){
  ...
  callback() // se ejecuta codigo 1
  ...
}

function funcion2(){
  ...
  callback() //se ejecuta codigo 2
  ...
}
```

Comment: Puede (_o no_) que las respuestas [en esta otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/480310/16597) te sean de utilidad.

Answer (score 0):

puedes tener un estado almacenado de tal manera que se consulte el estado y se ejecute un segmento de código u otro, por ejemplo:

```
const states = ['FUNC1', 'FUNC2']

function callback(state){
  if (state = 'FUNC1'){ 
    // Codigo1 ...
  } else if (state = 'FUNC2){
    // Codigo2 ...
  }
}


function funcion1(){
  ...
  callback('FUNC1') // se ejecuta codigo 1
  ...
}

function funcion2(){
  ...
  callback('FUNC2') //se ejecuta codigo 2
  ...
}
```